# Apache Toree with Anaconda Jupyter Notebook

Tags: hadoop, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I would like to seek for helps related to Anaconda Jupyter notebook.  I would like to write PySpark and SparkR in Jupyter notebook and I followed the online tutorial that teach how to install Apache Toree together with Jupyter notebook.

I am using the Cloudera Manager parcels to manage my kerberized Hadoop cluster.

However, I can't open the kernel for Apache Toree PySpark with the error below in the server log.

```
[I 15:24:50.529 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 15:24:52.079 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 8cb4838c-2171-4672-96a4-b21ef191ffc6
Starting Spark Kernel with SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark
WARNING: User-defined SPARK_HOME (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p2024.2115/lib/spark) overrides detected (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark).
WARNING: Running spark-class from user-defined location.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: joptsimple.OptionParser.acceptsAll(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljoptsimple/OptionSpecBuilder;
    at org.apache.toree.boot.CommandLineOptions.<init>(CommandLineOptions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.toree.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:25)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at org.apache.toree.Main$.main(Main.scala:24)
    at org.apache.toree.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I've put the jopt-simple-4.5.jar in the Toree lib and Spark home.  Is there any place that I have to put the jar there so that it can find it out when trying to create new notebook?  Thanks.

Best regards,
Ruka

Comment: I have this same issue. The link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOREE-324 says to recompile with jopt-simple 4.9. I have done recompiled with this change, but I need prod IT to deploy - so I cannot say it solves the issue. I have a current conversation on https://gitter.im/apache/toree for this topic - stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest solution I found is to add the following options to spark-submit:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/lib/toree-assembly-0.1.0-incubating.jar" --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/lib/toree-assembly-0.1.0-incubating.jar"
```

This can be added either to the `__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__` variable of the `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/kernel.json` file or directly to the bash command in the `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/bin/run.sh` file.

By adding this you force the classloader to load `joptsimple.OptionParser` from Toree JAR rather than from default CDH libraries.

P. S. Here is a Toree version that is compatible with CDH 5.10.0: https://github.com/Myllyenko/incubator-toree/releases

Comment: Your solution makes sense ... I've been toying with the configs to try this advice ... I am missing something. Did you add this conf line to Apache Toree's configs or edit the bash spark-submit file? Would you be so kind as to provide some specifics? Have you done anything else notable to get CDH (5.9.2 for me) working with Toree?

Comment: I've updated my answer but I'm not sure if it will work for CDH 5.9.2.
At the moment of posting this answer I was looking for a way to launch Toree with CDH 5.10.0. Later I ran into other problems (due to binary incompatibility between Apache Spark and Cloudera Spark libraries) and finally gave up with attempts to use default Toree assembly.
On Toree Gitter I was given an advice to recompile Toree against my Spark libraries. I'll let you know if I have success in this.

Comment: It seems that a CDH build / branch is a possible way to go. I am doing the same and also collaborating within the Gitter chat. CDH jars may not be in the repo, `repo1.maven.org`, Toree declares in `DependencyDownloader`. I browsed the repo & it does not seem to have them.

Comment: Take a look at my fork: https://github.com/Myllyenko/incubator-toree/tree/spark-1.6.0-cdh5.10.0
I almost did it :)